# Runtime error when pushing to a vector of a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I've been having run-time errors with this program for a few days now, and have finally been able to find what the issue is: the `push_back` function is for some reason never completing, leading to a crash.

The Constructor is fine, the `stringstream` is fine (I've `cout` tested both of them), but anything after `vctr[i].push_back(Pixel(r,g,b);` does not run whatsoever. The program will immediately time out at that point.

Also, it does the same thing when trying directly assign values to the vector. Ex: `vctr[i][j] = Pixel(r,g,b);`

Code in Question:

```
bool Picture::filetoVector(ifstream& fin, vector<vector<Pixel> >& vctr, int& cmax){
    string line, filetype;
    istringstream ssin;
    int width, height, r, g, b;

    //if fin fails to open file, return false & quite function.
    if(fin.fail()) return false;

    //This for loop grabs filetype, # of rows & columns (height & width), and cmax.
    for(int i = 0; getline(fin,line) && i < 3;i++){....}

    //This loop reads to vctr.
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            getline(fin,line);
            ssin.clear();
            ssin.str(line);

            ssin >> r >> g >> b;
            //This is where things are breaking.
            vctr[i].push_back(Pixel(r,g,b));
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Pixel Class:

```
struct Pixel{
    int red, green, blue;
    Pixel();
    Pixel(int r, int g, int b);
};
```

Pixel is very basic, containing only 3 integers and two Constructors. Pixel() sets red, green & blue to zero, Pixel(int r, int g, int b) sets red to r, green to g and so on.

filetoVector's call:

```
if(newpicture.filetoVector(filein, newvector, colorMax)){
    cout << "Error: unable to read PPM file " << inputFilename;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What does `Pixel` actually look like? And your outer loop looks suspicious. Are you expecting only 3 lines? Because it will read 4 lines since it evaluates the loop counter after reading a line first. If you want to read only 3 lines, move `getline()` inside the loop body. For that matter, the outer loop is ignoring the line it reads on each iteration, do you really want to do that? And have you pre-sized `vctr` to hold `height` number of elements before calling `fileToVector()`? You can't use `operator[]` to access non-existant elements

Comment: For all I know your `vctr` is too small and you're accessing it out of bouds. It'd be best if you could post a verifiable example. It's also likely you'd find the error while minimizing it.

Comment: What happens if after `for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){` and before `for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){` you put `vctr.emplace_back();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow Dante. You definitely did not post enough information to get a quick and smart answer here. You should post more code, specially:

- the one calling the function so that people can figure out how `vctr` is initialized.
- the Pixel class definition (does this one respect the rule of three? If not, pushing `Pixel` items to a vector is most likely unsafe)

I give it a try in "blind mode" anyway, you're most likely accessing `vctr` with an out-of-bound index when you do `vctr[i]`:

So you should simply do:

```
vctr.resize(height)
```

before your start the two nested for loops. To make sure there are `height` elements available in there...

Comment: This was correct, Also I apologize for the poor question. I went ahead and edited in the Pixel class and the filetoVector's call. Thank you, very much!